# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Trying to run my .py file from CMD, but it can't find the discord module

```
>>File 'C:\Users\\****\Desktop\Discord_Bot\main.py', line 1, in module

>>import discord 

>>ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

Although, when I run:

```
>>python 

>>import discord
```

It works as intended, any suggestions?

Comment: How are you running your `main.py` file?  Are you using the same interpreter?

Comment: Have you installed the discord module? https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, If I run it through pycharm it works, but if I try it through CMD I get the error.

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam Yes, I have installed it with pip. it shows up in my project interpreter.

Comment: To check the interpreter PyCharm is using, go to File > Settings > Project: name > Project Interpreter.  Then, in the CMD prompt, run `where python`.  If the two paths don't match, that's your problem.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, Just tried your suggestion, they are both in the same path.

Comment: Are you running your program in a virtual environment? If that's the case, maybe the main.py is looking for the discord dist-package inside the wrong folder. Can you try putting your script in Python's directory and run it from there?

Answer (score 5):

Go into the terminal and use: `pip uninstall discord.py` wait a few seconds so it can fully delete it, and then use `pip install discord.py`. Should work

Comment: Can you please add examples of full commands one has to type? That would make you answer easier to use.

Comment: Like this @Joooeey ?

Comment: yea much better :)
There's a problem with the backticks in the second piece of code. Using single backticks to enclose the ``code`` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's the Python version issue.

When I tried running in python3.8 I got the same error. Switched over to 3.6 and it worked.

Comment: Please don't write answers in a way that makes them look like questions.
There are systems in place to check for Not An Answer (NAA) posts.
This answer was falsely picked up by one of them. Please consider editing it to look more like an answer. Please remove "Not sure if this will help but maybe it's the python version the issue." and "Sorry for the late response :)" parts.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo pip install discord.py` solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
pip install discord
```

instead of installing discord.py. Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

check for python interpreter location in pycharm. Or install discord with sudo pip command

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that your venv in pycharm and your environment in the command prompt have different packages installed. If the error is the program not running at command prompt try opening a command prompt and running `pip install discord` (pip must be in your PATH) to install it to your main python directory. You'll notice that in PyCharm if you open the terminal tab it says

> (venv) C:\Your\File\Structure

with "(venv)" meaning a virtual environment is loaded here that can have packages installed to it without altering your main installation on your PC (usually located at C:\Program Files\Python 3.5). In order to run scripts from the command line, however, you will need the package to be installed in your main python directory which `pip install discord` will accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file name its diferent the module you're trying to import (discord.py in your case)
If its not the case,you can try `pip install discord --force-reinstall`. It may solve your problem

Comment: use comment section for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

So, I encountered the same issue. I tried everything mentioned above but nothing worked. It turns out that my filename was `discord.py`. This was the thing causing the real problem. So, you shall also check your filename. I believe it implies to other packages as well. So

#### Never use package names for your file.

Answer (score 0):

discord has changed its name to yeirne discord.abc has become
try:
`import discord.abc`

Answer (score 0):

You can try install it manually.
If you have git, you can use:

```
git clone https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py.git
```

Then, go into the directory and use:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

You can also check to see if the Python path is correct, or if your Python version is supported by Discord.py. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the file. Instead of Discord.py or main.py, try to use something like Beta1.py or NewBeta.py . It must run