# Python docker keeps saying module not found

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, discord.py, python-docker

I am trying to build a docker to host my Discord bot.
The dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.8
COPY ./Elevate/* /docker/
RUN python3.8 -m pip install discord.py==1.5.1
RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r docker/requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "/docker/bot.py"]
```

and `docker-build . -t bot` works fine. However, when I try to run the docker, I get

```
  File "/docker/bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

When building the docker, I can see that it successfully installed `discord==1.5.1`

requirements.txt contains:

```
discord.py == 1.5.1
dblpy
python-dateutil
babel
aiohttp-requests
parsedatetime
wavelink
pillow
statcord.py
jishaku
ksoftapi
```

I'm pretty new to docker, so if this is a stupid mistake, please don't judge :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886183/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-discord

Comment: 100% reproduceable? Ok here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the requirements.txt from

```
discord.py == 1.5.1
```

to

```
discord.py==1.5.1
```

It's a best practice to maintain a `requirements.lock`. You can generate the lock file by running `pip freeze > requirements.lock` in the docker container.

Sample Command:
`docker exec -it <image> pip freeze > requirements.lock`